# Is there a way to find and replace on columns in vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code to rewrite some SQL, and I am trying to rename a bunch of columns. I am basically trying to take the column name from the table and replace the underscore with a space. I can do multi-select for the chunk I want to rename (holding alt + shift and dragging), but the find and replace seems to only allow a select number of rows, or the entire doc. In my case, doing a find and replace only on the selected text after the "AS" keyword.

```
    position_key                 AS "Position Key"
    COMPANY_KEY                  AS "COMPANY_KEY"
```

Does anyone know if there is a way to have find and replace on only half of a row? It seems like that should be available, but I can't figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: I want to find the "_" in the string on the left of "AS" and replace it with a space. In the example above, line 1 is what I want, line 2 needs to have action taken.

Comment: You mean the `_` to the right of the `AS`?  That is the one being removed?

Comment: create a feature request to add the option "Inside selection". Then with multiple cursor you can make complex  selections.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`(AS\s+)(".+)?(_)(.+")$`

and replace with

`$1$2 $4`

---

It is very easy to select a column of information with multi-cursors.  But that won't help because the "Find in Selection" option in the Find widget has what I would call a bug.  It will only find in the first selection not all of them ;{

See this issue https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/38363 (Search in selection does not support multi-selections
) Please **upvote** the issue.

If you want to know how to select a column of text with multi-cursors) nonetheless, here is how:

1. Put cursor at your top starting point.
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>DownArrow</kbd> as far down as you wish.
3. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>RightArrow</kbd> on Windows)

In your case you do want the column of selection to go all the way to the end of the lines.  If this were not the case, you could use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>RightArrow</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>RightArrow</kbd> to select in smaller increments.

Answer (score 0):

With multi cursor you can do a workaround

1. make a selection with multi cursor
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (Copy the selection)
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> (Create a new file)
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (Paste each individual selection to a new line)
5. perform your Search Replace
6. Make a multi cursor selection from each line from first till last char
7. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (Copy the selection)
8. Goto original file, multi selection is still active
9. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (Paste each individual selection over the original content)

In your case for step 1:

1. Select `AS` (There is one or more spaces in front of `AS`)
2. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to select next similar or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to selct all

There is a limit to how many multi cursors you can have but 10000 is often enough.